# fsck says a partition is mounted in Ubuntu Recovery Mode

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, filesystem-corruption, fsck

I ran Ubuntu 18.10's Recovery Mode and `fsck` failed saying `dev/sda7 is mounted`. I tried unmounting it only to be told that "it is busy". I'd appreciate any hints on solving this.

The partition `dev/sda7` is actually the partition where Ubuntu is installed. EDIT: If it has any relevance, I'm using an SSD.

Comment: Boot from an USB drive and then do the check.

Comment: I already tried that using Ubuntu Live USB (my bad, I didn't mention it), but I couldn't run fsck because it said that the drive is 'in use'. I also tried unmounting the drive's partitions, but it still reported the same error. I wonder if there's actually a recovery mode for the Ubuntu Live USB.

Comment: Try an alternative rescue disk designed for recovery.

Comment: Could you please suggest me one such disk?

Comment: First one that springs to mind is http://www.trinityhome.org (for TRK), followed by SystemRescue at http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/   but look at https://www.fossmint.com/linux-rescue-recovery-tools/